# Filtering RDD based on column values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a file in spark with following table data

Property ID|Location|Price|Bedrooms|Bathrooms

I have read this file as rdd using :-

```
a = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/realestate.txt")
```

Now I need to find

b. Create a RDD of Property IDs having 3 bedrooms

c. Create another RDD of Property IDs having at least 2 bathrooms

How to select a column in rdd and filter the table according to the column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `filter` the RDDs using lambda functions:

```
b = a.filter(lambda r: int(r.split('|')[3]) == 3 if r.split('|')[0] != 'Property ID' else True)
c = a.filter(lambda r: int(r.split('|')[4]) >= 2 if r.split('|')[0] != 'Property ID' else True)
```

Comment: I was doing it this way  1) First removing the header  2) Using the filter function     `c=a.filter(lambda x: "Price" not in x)
b = c.filter(lambda r: (r.split('|')[3]) == '3')`                                                                                  Is there a way i can add the header back ?

Comment: Well, you filtered it away :) that's why I didn't filter but use an `if` statement instead. You can put it back using a union, but it's more cumbersome than keeping the header and putting an `if` statement inside the lambda function

Comment: You are also removing the header by keeping else statement as False.  If we do `else ["Property ID","Location","Price","Bedrooms","Bathrooms"])` then header also remains there.

Comment: @Anil oh yes, sorry. should be `else True`.